# Импорт модулей Python в C#

Tags: python, c#, wpf, ironpython

Создал проект в WPF и хочу запустить с помощью IronPython файл.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Users\duett\PycharmProjects\CV2All\main.py");
    }
}
```

но C# не видит модуль cv, модуль находиться в venv.

Comment: Что-то похожее: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77701135/21103781

Comment: @wchistow посмотрел, принципе описано было логично, но код не соответствует ( 
может быть знаете как правильно можно будет запустить?